# Git Install only command line tools

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode

I need to install git and command line development tools as 'make' or 'cc' to install rbenv and Ruby. Is 'Command Line Tools' package enough ? I do not want to install XCode if is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution

- Download & install from Apple Dev Center **Command Line Tools** (requirement) https://developer.apple.com
- Install **Homebrew** [Link](https://brew.sh/)
- Install **Git** (or other package) via Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

You can download an extra package from the Apple Developer site, you can even just get a copy of Git as a typically install package or apps like Source Tree will give you an option to install it yourself.